Chazon Ish: tochachah is about helping oneself
This article says (footnote 22):

At the end of his book on Taharot, the Chazon Ish writes that klal
Yisrael is one unit; when a person gives tochachah to improve the
conduct of others, he is in reality helping himself.

I can’t find any such passage in the Chazon Ish on Taharot.
However, the article’s citations are extremely unreliable. Footnote 23 refers to a non-existent book called Or ha-Chaim by the Maharam Shick, whereas the relevant passage is actually found in his responsa on Orach Chaim; and footnote 4 refers to a non-existent book called Batei ha-L’vi’im by the Brisker Rav, whereas the relevant passage is actually found in his chiddushim to Masechet Sotah.
So my suspicion is that the Chazon Ish did say what’s attributed to him but that he maybe wrote it somewhere else. Any thoughts?

If the intent is slightly misquoted and is referring to the chazon ish explaining how praying for a person's spiritual success is not a contradiction to free choice due to it being a manifestation of the prayers free will. It is on the bottom of the last page before emunah ubitachon in the chazon ish on taharos shown here  In the paragraph on the bottom starting with divarim 5.

"... than it is missing from the Hebrew books edition." Isn't this page from the Hebrew books edition the same page you bring?

@TamirEvan , you are correct, I am mistaken, thank you.
